# Redis Cluster Metrics vs. Benchmark Results

Tags: kubernetes, redis, azure-aks, metrics, redis-cluster

I have setup a Redis Cluster installation in our K8s Cluster (AKS) using the official Helm Chart (https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis-cluster).
We went with the default values, but only activated the metrics endpoint.

This gives me a 6-node-redis-cluster.

I then ran a benchmark against this cluster using memtier_benchmark and the following command:

```
kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never memtier --image=redislabs/memtier_benchmark:latest -- memtier_benchmark -h my-redis-cluster.redis-cluster -d 500 -c 1 -n 2000000 -a PASSWORD --cluster-mode
```

This shows the following output

```
[RUN #1 100%, 129 secs]  0 threads:     8000000 ops,   46381 (avg:   61859) ops/sec, 4.22MB/sec (avg: 5.35MB/sec),  0.09 (avg:  0.17) msec latency

4         Threads
1         Connections per thread
2000000   Requests per client


ALL STATS
======================================================================================================================================================
Type         Ops/sec     Hits/sec   Misses/sec    MOVED/sec      ASK/sec    Avg. Latency     p50 Latency     p99 Latency   p99.9 Latency       KB/sec
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sets         5565.70          ---          ---         0.00         0.00         0.19415         0.13500         1.25500         5.24700      2977.91
Gets        55656.68       554.52     55102.16         0.00         0.00         0.16497         0.11100         1.15100         4.83100      2440.43
Waits           0.00          ---          ---          ---          ---             ---             ---             ---             ---          ---
Totals      61222.37       554.52     55102.16         0.00         0.00         0.16762         0.11900         1.16700         4.86300      5418.34
```

So, according to this benchmark in total, 8 million commands were sent at a rate of ~ 61k / second.

When i compare this with the metrics i get from the metrics endpoint, it shows me much lower values.

For example (taken from http://my-redis-cluster-metrics.redis-cluster:9121/metrics inside my cluster):

```
redis_commands_processed_total 275459
redis_total_writes_processed 16081
redis_total_reads_processed 272649
```

How do those values fit together? I would expect to see 8 million total commands processed in total.

I try to build reasonable dashboards based on those metrics and would like to find out what our actual throughput is but something seems a bit off which i can not understand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.